# Cálculo de Intervalos en RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

Tengo un par de dudas a ver si me pueden ayudar.

Dispongo de una tabla de datos en que se observa la velocidad y la distancia recorrida

| Veloc | Dist |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | 2 |
| 4 | 10 |
| 7 | 4 |
| 7 | 22,8 |
| 8 | 16,3 |
| 9 | 10,4 |
| ... | ... |

Mi primera duda es, ¿se pueden sustituir las comas por puntos? Como es un archivo csv, para trabajar con él, pude hacer un reemplazar los valores con Excel, pero me gustaría saber si es posible hacerlo directamente en R. Lo he buscado, pero no he encontrado como hacerlo.

La siguiente cuestión es, he calculado la frecuencia de la velocidad, pero quiero que me lo haga en intervalos [0-5], [6-10], [11-15], etc.
Al realizar lo siguiente:

```
v <- as.data.frame(table(veloc = factor(cut(datos$veloc, breaks = 5))))
```

Me da unos intervalos creados al azar, como estos:

```
intervalos  frec 
(3.98,8.2]    5
(8.2,12.4]   10
(12.4,16.6]   13
…
```

Me los coge de 3.98 a 8.2, de 8.2 a 12.4…
Sería posible que estos intervalos fuesen números enteros como he comentado antes, es decir
([0-5], [6-10]…)?

Gracias por adelantado.

Saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con respecto a convertir las comas por puntos, claro que se puede, tu columna evidentemente como esta importada debería ser una cadena, por lo que es simple usando `gsub()`:

```
as.numeric(gsub(",", ".", c("1,2", "3.14")))
[1] 1.20 3.14
```

Y en tu caso, algo así

```
datos$dist <- as.numeric(gsub(",", ".", datos$dist))
```

Sin embargo, esto es todavía más sencillo, si usas `read.csv()` para leer el archivo, esta función cuenta con el parámetro `dec` con el cual establecer el separador de decimales, por ejemplo `dec = ","`

Ahora, con respecto a los rangos, en primer lugar, si a `cut()` le indicas la cantidad de rangos que quieres, este los calcula automáticamente, pero no al azar, se calculan básicamente para que cada rango tenga aproximadamente la misma longitud. Sin embargo, nada te impide definir tus propios rangos, claro que previamente debes conocer los limites de tu vector:

```
> x <- sample(1:9, 100, replace = TRUE) * runif(10)
> x
  [1] 4.38291731 2.27174776 0.02358342 2.69440256 0.13633384 0.13181449 2.59019489 4.75009701
  [9] 3.02371568 4.23916332 0.97398162 1.62267697 0.02358342 3.23328308 0.13633384 0.08238405
 [17] 0.64754872 0.67858529 1.88982230 3.53263610 1.94796325 2.59628315 0.10612541 1.07776103
 [25] 0.09088923 0.01647681 4.53284107 6.10726758 0.75592892 4.23916332 2.43495406 1.62267697
 [33] 0.10612541 2.69440256 0.09088923 0.11533768 4.53284107 1.35717057 1.88982230 4.23916332
 [41] 4.38291731 2.92081855 0.03537514 2.15552205 0.18177846 0.14829130 2.59019489 4.75009701
 [49] 1.13389338 2.82610888 1.94796325 2.59628315 0.07075027 1.07776103 0.04544461 0.08238405
 [57] 3.23774362 1.35717057 1.88982230 2.82610888 2.43495406 2.92081855 0.03537514 3.77216359
 [65] 0.27266768 0.09886087 3.23774362 2.03575586 3.02371568 0.70652722 0.97398162 2.92081855
 [73] 0.08254199 0.53888051 0.09088923 0.14829130 5.18038979 2.03575586 1.13389338 2.11958166
 [81] 2.43495406 2.27174776 0.08254199 3.23328308 0.31811230 0.06590724 3.23774362 2.03575586
 [89] 1.13389338 2.11958166 2.43495406 0.32453539 0.10612541 2.69440256 0.36355691 0.01647681
 [97] 0.64754872 0.67858529 3.40168014 6.35874498

> cut(x, breaks=c(0,2,4,6,8,10))
  [1] (4,6] (2,4] (0,2] (2,4] (0,2] (0,2] (2,4] (4,6] (2,4] (4,6] (0,2] (0,2] (0,2] (2,4] (0,2] (0,2]
 [17] (0,2] (0,2] (0,2] (2,4] (0,2] (2,4] (0,2] (0,2] (0,2] (0,2] (4,6] (6,8] (0,2] (4,6] (2,4] (0,2]
 [33] (0,2] (2,4] (0,2] (0,2] (4,6] (0,2] (0,2] (4,6] (4,6] (2,4] (0,2] (2,4] (0,2] (0,2] (2,4] (4,6]
 [49] (0,2] (2,4] (0,2] (2,4] (0,2] (0,2] (0,2] (0,2] (2,4] (0,2] (0,2] (2,4] (2,4] (2,4] (0,2] (2,4]
 [65] (0,2] (0,2] (2,4] (2,4] (2,4] (0,2] (0,2] (2,4] (0,2] (0,2] (0,2] (0,2] (4,6] (2,4] (0,2] (2,4]
 [81] (2,4] (2,4] (0,2] (2,4] (0,2] (0,2] (2,4] (2,4] (0,2] (2,4] (2,4] (0,2] (0,2] (2,4] (0,2] (0,2]
 [97] (0,2] (0,2] (2,4] (6,8]
Levels: (0,2] (2,4] (4,6] (6,8] (8,10]
>
```

Nota: Si eventualmente no tienes claro los límites superiores e inferiores, podrías hacer algo así: `cut(x, breaks=c(-Inf,2,4,6,8,Inf))`

Comment: Hola Patricio,
Perfecto muchas gracias ahora sí lo entendí y me funcionó :).
Saludos